# Feed python function with a variable number of arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a script that reads a variable number of fields from an input file and pass them to a function as arguments. For example:

> file 1 with fields: A,B and C   => `function(A,B,C)`
>
> file N with fields: A,B,C and D => `function(A,B,C,D)`

My question is: How to feed the function with the right number of fields accordingly to the input file?.

PD: Of course the function accepts any number of arguments

Comment: Can you show us the relevant piece of code?

Comment: why are lists not relevant here ?

Comment: Should the function be able to tell if it receives the correct number of arguments based on which file you are using? Otherwise, it's just a simple matter of declaring `def function(*args)`, and `function` can take any number of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the fields (arguments) into a list and then use [argument unpacking](http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments):

```
function(*fields)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def func(*args):
...     return args
...
>>> fields = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> func(*fields)
('A', 'B', 'C')
>>> fields = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
>>> func(*fields)
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use args and kwargs like this:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
  pass
```

in this way you can get positional and named parameters, args should be a list of values, holding the positional arguments, kwargs should be a dictionary, its keys the argument name with its value